# MySQL root account unable to create database

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried 6 different forum rooms with a similar issue none of the solutions are working out for me.

Install MariaDB on my Raspberry Pi, which I am logging in via putty from my windows machine.

On Pi terminal I log in to MySQL via 'sudo mysql -u  root -p enter the password, I have also tried logging without sudo. either way I can login to MariaDB

The issue is I have no Grants so when I enter the following command

```
MariaDB [(none)]>SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost
```

the following is my output

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-----                              ------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                                 
|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----                              ------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 
 '*2470C0C06DEE                              42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19' |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 -----                              ------------------------------+
```

so when I login via phpMyadmin  I am unable to create or access anything.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
mysql-secure_installation 
sudo service mysql restart
```

tried viewing User table

```
  SELECT USER,HOST,PLUGIN FROM MYSQL.USER

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO '[root]'@'[hostname]' IDENTIFIED BY 
'[helpmelikehell]' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

as well as *.* replace by '%'  nothing seem to be working any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: This has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. It is a MySQL problem. You should better ask at https://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not a specific Pi problem, try the following

- stop the mysql server
- start mysql with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
- log in to mysql and grant the correct privileges
- at the end: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
- shutdown with `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`
- restart normally

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried the above and I can't even shut down as it states mysqladmin shutdown failed error access denied you need at least one of the shutdown privileges for this operation.  It seems to me I can't even kill the process, any other suggestion are most welcome

Comment: `sudo systemctl stop mysqld.service`  should stop it. If even that fails, `sudo systemctl disable mysqld.service` to make sure that it doesn't start at boot, and then reboot the pi.